# Start intent from BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android

My application receives SMS and changes to activity to display an alert dialog box in my app. `Toast` is working well, but it will not change the activity. `onReceive()` takes SMS that contain email and depending upon that email id my app searches the associated contact number and sends it back in a reply message.

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
{
    // Get SMS map from Intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String messages = "";

    if ( extras != null )
    {
        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

        // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
        //ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
        {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
            messages += body + "\n";

            // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS
            // I added encrypting of all received SMS 


        }

        // Display SMS message
        Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(context,AlertActivity.class);
       // context.startActivity(i);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    }
```

Comment: why you comment this `context.startActivity(i);` line?

Answer (score 2):

you are adding `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` after starting AlertActivity Activity.  use this way :

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,AlertActivity.class);

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

context.startActivity(i);
```